# how can reach struct content with KeyValuePair in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, stream, key-value

This is my method and the problem is the innerKey. Value is struct and in txt file just I have the name of struct not the struct content. `state` is nested dic that the object is another dic.

How can i write struct content in my txt file?

```
private void show2(Dictionary<string, object> state)
{
    TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(savepath2);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> group1 in state)
    {

        Dictionary<string, object> group2 = (Dictionary<string, object>)group1.Value;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> innerKey in group2)
        {

            tw2.WriteLine("Id: {0} -- Type: {1} -- Value: {2}",group1.Key, innerKey.Key, innerKey.Value);
            tw2.Close();
        }

    }
    
}
```

Or is there any way to write the nested dictionary as object as input file in a  txt file with stream path similar to serialize method? I don´t want to serialize it because I want to be able to check txt content:

```
private void SaveFile(object state)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(savepath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, state);
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: its C# in unity

Comment: If the InnerKey.Value is a struct, what is it you're trying to display from that struct?

Comment: struct content may be every thing - for example i have int and string in this case